# Decentralized search engine for my website

Tags: elasticsearch, search, search-engine

I am trying to build a search engine for my website but I want it to be decentralized. I have a database of documents and I will build an inverted index and then I want to decentralize index servers. Could you please suggest what to do in this case and where to start my project at? Can I use elasticsearch for indexing and add decentralization on top of it?

I am new to decentralization and so, any help or links to start building a decentralized search engine will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider using RediSearch.io?

Answer (score 0):

Using ElasticSearch would be perfect for your use-case.
Quoting from elasticSearch's website -

> Elasticsearch is a distributed, RESTful search and analytics engine capable of solving a growing number of use cases.

ElasticSearch clusters are basically a group of nodes each running the ES service.
For storing your data and to make it searchable you define indices, (an index is basically the structure that defines what your data looks like), by defining the index mapping.

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "students" : {
            "properties" : {
                "studentId" : { "type" : "keyword" },
"admissionDate" : {"type":"Date"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about mappings from here - [ElasticSearch Mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/mapping.html)

A good place to start your overall journey with elasticSearch would be to read the getting started documentation - [ElasticSearch Getting Started](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/getting-started.html)

The CRUD operations for an index in ES are provided by - [Indices APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/indices.html)

You store(Index) data in an ES index - [Document APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/docs.html)

You can search your indexed data using the different Search APIs that ES provides - [Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search.html) and Query DSL (Query Language for ES) - [ES Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl.html)

As far as your concern your for a distributed system, you can create a cluster with more than one nodes with each node running on a different server, ES internally takes care of routing the requests between different nodes in the cluster. Just adding the correct cluster name in the node's elasticsearch.yml would add that node in the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the information. 
If you excuse my naivete, can I build blockchain like network of my app/website which uses elasticsearch as the index for searching?

Comment: would be helpful if you could explain the use case, a bit more.